# How to create a slide that shows hidden buttons and the name of all buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

How to create a slide that shows hidden buttons? There is a list of buttons, some of which are hidden.

You need to create a simple slide / switch on pure JS without any effects, which when you clicked on the "next" button switched to the next button, and if it is hidden, then showed this hidden button, when switching to the next hidden button, the previous one should disappear, and the current should appear. When switching to the main div, the name of the current button should be recorded, regardless of whether it is hidden or not.

When switching to hidden buttons, the main buttons must maintain their state.

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
    var currentSlide = 0;

    function nextSlide() {
      goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    }

    function previousSlide() {
      goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    }

    function goToSlide(n) {
      slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
      currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
      // console.log(currentSlide);
      var l = slides[currentSlide].className = 'btn';
      // console.log(l);
    }

    next.onclick = function () {
      nextSlide();
    };
    previous.onclick = function () {
      previousSlide();
    };
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; } 
    .visible { display: block; }
```

```html
<!-- List with buttons -->
     <ul>
        <li class="slide visible"><button class="btn" name="Visible One"/>Button Visible One</li> 
        <li class="slide visible"><button class="btn" name="Visible Two"/>Button Visible Two</li> 
        <li class="slide hidden"><button class="btn" name="Hidden One"/>Button Hidden One</li> 
        <li class="slide hidden"><button class="btn" name="Hidden Two"/>Button Hidden Two</li>
    </ul> 
    
    <div class="result"><p>Здесь должен быть name кнопки</p></div>
    
    <!-- Movement buttons -->
    <button id="previous">Previos</button>  
    <button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Where is Your JavaScript code?

Comment: Here is the code from my project. but he does not know how to display hidden buttons.

Comment: there are typos in your code, for example there isn't any `#slide` element. Furthermore you are using `next.onclick` and `previous.onclick` but you haven't defined it nowhere

Comment: You do not pay attention to the JC code, I specifically formulated my question, and this code is only a fragment of my mistakes.